# Is it possible to undeclare or define a null bean in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

While using Spring, I've encountered a scenario in which some logic is called if a particular bean is not null.  I do not want this logic to be called; therefore, I need this object to be null.  The bean in question has a default non-null value created by autoconfiguration.

My question is this: is there a way to "undeclare" a bean so that it's null?

This won't work:

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return null;
}
```

It yields:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'userDetailsService' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean'
```

Is there an Spring configuration way to do this or do I have to dive in and call constructors and setters to set this object to null?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you are using an annotation (e.g @Service) for UserDetailsService class definition?

Comment: Have you tried to cast null to a type? `return (UserDetailsService) null;`

Comment: Why declare it in the first place? Realistically the answer is no there isn't. Maybe more details on the issue you have with defining the bean and why you do not need it will help give a concise answer to your issue

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you do not want UserDetailsService to be treated as a bean, therefore you shouldn't create it as one. Remove annotations setting it up as a bean (e.g @Service, @Bean)

Comment: This does not solve the problem.  Removing the `@Bean` annotation from the `UserDetailsService` declaration causes spring to inject a bean of type `InMemoryUserDetailsService`, which is the default.  I do not want this behavior; I want the userDetailsService field on this object to be null.